# Excel - Selecting a Range of Cells With Exclusion based on Criteria

Tags: excel

I'm working with Excel 2010. I want to create a selection of cells from Column B for my chart's x-axis, but I don't want to include all the cells within this range. Typically ranges are expressed in the format of:

```
=ColumnB!$B$1:$B$100
```

Let's say that column B is filled with values between -100 to 100. I want to create a range using a formula that excludes cells that have a value less than zero. I  know the dirty(?) trick of creating another column based on a formula like:

```
=IF(B1<0, B1, "")
```

and then using this new column in my chart's x-axis, but I'm wondering if I can skip having to create any columns and use a formulaic/dynamic way of generating the range necessary.

Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: Nothing dirty about `=IF(B1<0, B1, "")`. Even cleaner (in my opinion) is to use `NA()` rather than an empty string: `=IF(B1<0, B1, NA())`

Comment: what about a pivot chart? There you can filter your values.

Comment: @Máté Juhász I'm not following how to implement that in a PivotChart. Is there a link/sample to point me towards?

Comment: @CallumDA No, and I'm not denigrating the option. but I find it more efficient to just use a formula directly in the chart series expression especially if I have multiple sets I want to highlight within a large dataset.

Comment: [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotChart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) is the official tutorial on pivot chart. If you need more help please post some sample data.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I think I misspoke. I know the basics of PivotCharts and how to create them. I was asking about the specific implementation for the dynamic range in question. For sample data, please see the 2nd paragraph of the question for set-up beginning with the text "Let's say..."